# Reverse proxy using Tomcat 10 url-rewrite RewriteValve

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, tomcat9, tomcat10

I am trying to implement a reverse proxy using tomcat 10 url-rewrite. I have extended RewriteValue class and overridden invoke().

```
public class DynamicRewriteValue extends RewriteValve{
    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        // Apply dynamic rules for redirection
        if (isBlacklisted(requestURI)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        if (isWhitelisted(requestURI)) {
            // Perform the whitelisted redirect
            System.out.println("request context is : "+request.getContextPath());
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8888/new-url");
            return;
        }


        super.invoke(request, response);
    }

    public boolean isBlacklisted(String url){
        return url.contains("black");
    }

    public boolean isWhitelisted(String url){
        return url.contains("white");
    }
}
```

and i have specified in this class in server.xml file.

```
<Valve className="org.example.rewrite.DynamicRewriteValue" />
```

and imported the jar into the lib file.

My question is the request is being send to specified endpoint but the request is not being proxied. ie if i access

```
http://localhost:8080/white
```

the request is forwarded to

```
http://localhost:8888/new-url
```

but i need the request should be like

```
http://localhost:8080/new-url
```

and it should get the result from the "http://localhost:8888/new-url".

can anyone please help me to understand how can we implement reverse proxy using tomcat 10 url-rewrite?